# Listing all services in AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to list every service in a given account, without having to look at billing information. Is there any way to get that programmatically?

Comment: Kindly show the work you have done so far and elaborate more on the language used and the question to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it programmatically then you need to enable [Cloud watch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) feature which will be billed seperately and call it (cloud watch) via API or SDK , or Else you can use the API's and SDK's of all the services to get the running services .

Comment: Sorry, which feature in CloudWatch are you referring to? It's not clear how this answers the question.

Comment: The account has just cloud trail enabled not cloud watch. I am using AWS SDK for java. The requirement is to check services enabled in the account and then do some processing on the resources used in each service.